# InnoDB:  удаление записей из базы с удалением с жесткого диска

Tags: mysql

Как известно, при удалении записей из mysql таблиц innodb место на жестком диске не очищается. Возможно ли все таки как-то его почистить ? Система FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

только экспорт/импорт бд

Comment: то есть сделать дамп бд, потом удалить ее вообще то есть drop database db, снова создать и восстановить из дампа ?